# angular treats whitepace as null with ng-options

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-options

In controller, i have an array like this

```
    'Pipe': '|',
    'Comma': ',',
    'Tab': '\t'
  };
```

and in ng-options, im using it like this

```
<select 
    ng-model="csv.delimiter"
    ng-options="value as key for (key, value) in delimiters">
</select>
```

When i print the value csv.delimiter, it shows correct value for pipe and comma but for tab it shows null. It shows null for space and other escape characters also.
Please help

I expect non-null value for tab, space or any other escape character

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing the behavior you describe. Tab is a valid choice and the model is appropriately set to the tab character. See the demo below.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MainController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.delimiters = {
    Pipe: '|',
    Comma: ',',
    Tab: '\t'
  };
  
  var arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
  
  $scope.setData = function (delimiter) {
    // For demo purposes. This is not spec to delimit
    // data by a character.
    $scope.data = arr.join(delimiter);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">
  <select 
      ng-model="csv.delimiter"
      ng-options="value as key for (key, value) in delimiters"
      ng-change="setData(csv.delimiter)">
  </select>
  <br />
  {{csv.delimiter}}
  <br />
  Is Pipe: {{csv.delimiter===delimiters.Pipe}}
  <br />
  Is Comma: {{csv.delimiter===delimiters.Comma}}
  <br />
  Is Tab: {{csv.delimiter===delimiters.Tab}}
  <br />
  <textarea ng-model="data">
  
  </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: it is working in my case also if i write the code separate to my app, but in app, it is displaying null for tab

Comment: I think you will need to update your question to be more specific to reproduce the problem then. Are you using a different version of angularjs, if so which? Is there anything else unique about your app that is different than the setup code here?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra "\" before escape characters. For example, for tab use \ \t

Comment: That would give the string of two characters: backslash and 't'. The intention is to get a single tab character.